# R : add a code to save a displayed heatmap inside a function

Tags: r

I'm facing an issue related to a download of a vizualisation in .png format (I've also tried with .jpeg format).

I have a function which contains my code. Inside there is a chunk of code that create heatmap with the package ComplexHeatmap and the dedicated function Heatmap(). I would like to save the vizualisation of the picture.

Here is the problem, when I execute all the chunks of code one by one, without using my function, it works well. However, when I execute my function, build with these chunks of code, it runs well but the vizualisation saved display a white screen.

Can someone help me out with this behavior ?

Thank you in advance for your advice !

```r
if( ! "ComplexHeatmap" %in% .packages(all.available=T) ){ install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap") }
library(ComplexHeatmap)

set.seed(123)
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 6; nc2 = 8; nc3 = 10; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
)
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat) = paste0("row", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat) = paste0("column", seq_len(nc))


myFunction<-function(data){
  png( file=enc2native("picture.png"),width=650, height=800)
  Heatmap(data)
  dev.off()
}


myFunction(mat)
```

Comment: myFunction<-function(data){
  png( file=enc2native("picture.png"),width=650, height=800)
  print(Heatmap(data))
  dev.off()
}